# Removing item from list in for loop removes from both lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1

for i, x in enumerate(list2):
    print(list1, list2)
    del list2[i]
```

returns

```
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
[2, 3] [2, 3]
[2] [2]
```

when I expect it to return

```
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3] [2, 3]
[1, 2, 3] [2]
```

I am new to python and was wondering if I am doing something wrong or missing something.

edit:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1.copy()

for i in list1:
    print(list1, list2)
    list2.remove(i)
```

fixed it

Comment: It is because list2 is a reference to list1 rather than being an entirely new list. So whatever happens to list 2 happens to list 1.

Comment: how can i make list2 the same as list1 but a new list

Comment: `list2 = list1.copy()`

Comment: Also, do you want your expected output to end on [2] or [3]?

Comment: list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1.copy()

for i in list1:
    print(list1, list2)
    list2.remove(i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve this, you need to create a copy of `x` into a new item which can be done with the `copy` module

```
from copy import copy

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = copy(list1)

for i, x in enumerate(list2):
    print(list1, list2)
    del list2[i]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!